# One to Many Relationship with Join Table using EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-many, join

I have a question about how to configure the one to many relationship with a join table using Code First fluent API.  I have a Company, Contact Object both share a common Address Object like below

```
Class Address {
       public int AddressId
       .....
    }

Class Company {
   public int CompanyId
   ......
   public virtual ICollection<Address> Address
}

Class Contact {
   public int ContactID
   .......
   public virtual ICollection<Address> Address
}
```

My expected DB structure would be

```
Company Table
   CompanyId PK NOT NULL
   .....

Contact Table
    ContactId PK NOT NULL
    .....

Address Table
    AddressId PK NOT NULL
    .....

CompanyAddress Table
    CompanyId NOT NULL
    AddressId NOT NULL

ContactAddress Table
    ContactId NOT NULL
    AddressId NOT NULL
```

I was able to achieve this by using the below fluent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
  .HasMany(c => c.Address)
  .WithMany()
  .Map(m =>
    {
      m => m.MapLeftKey("CompanyId")
            .MapRightKey("AddressId")
            .ToTable("CompanyAddress")});

modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
  .HasMany(c => c.Address)
  .WithMany()
  .Map(m =>
    {
      m => m.MapLeftKey("ContactId")
            .MapRightKey("AddressId")
            .ToTable("ContactAddress")});
```

but EF start to treat Company and Address as Many to Many relationship and when I try to delete Company or Contacts it does not delete the corresponding Address record(since EF treats them as many to many), how can I define this type of relationship using EF with cascading delete option.  I searched for more than 3 days and was suprised no one has talked or raised this type of scenarios, so wondering whether my approach is wrong or the answer is very trivial.

Comment: Your question seems to be about cascade deletes more than many-to-many relationships. Maybe the question's title should be something more like "How do I prevent cascade deletes in EF?"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have that with the many-to-many (it's what you're creating
 - and what you described).

When you delete company / contact - the 'join' table records get deleted.

You can simplify that and just do this in your config (remove all you have):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
    .HasMany(c => c.Address)
    .WithOptional()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
    .HasMany(c => c.Address)
    .WithOptional()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: But how do I mention the joining table name and the columns of the joining table?

Comment: I forgot about your post entirely:) You can do that - but then you have other issues, it's either this or that. You want too much I think. If you have many-to-many - you can't have cascade delete the way you want it. I can give you a proper manually set up many-to-many - but again its useless for what you want.