# EF Doesn't Delete Records For Fluent API - Many To Many Relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, fluent-interface, entity-framework-migrations

I have 2 entities,

- News
- FileAttachment

I wanted to configure using code-first fluent API so that Each News can have 0,1 or more than 1 attachments.

here is what i'm using right now

```
   public NewsMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("News"); // Table Name
        this.HasKey(m => m.Id); // Primary Key

        // Field Definition            
        this.Property(m => m.Title).HasMaxLength(255).IsRequired();
        this.Property(m => m.Body).HasColumnType("Text").IsRequired();
        this.Property(m => m.Summary).HasMaxLength(1000).IsRequired();
        this.Property(m => m.AuthorId).IsRequired();

        this.Property(m => m.CreatedOn).IsRequired();
        this.Property(m => m.UpdatedOn).IsRequired();

        this.HasMany(m => m.Attachments).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("NewsId").MapRightKey("AttachmentId"));
    }

public class FileAttachmentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FileAttachment>
{
    public FileAttachmentMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("FileAttachments"); // Table Name
        this.HasKey(m => m.Id); // Primary Key

        // Field Definition            
        this.Property(m => m.DisplayName).HasMaxLength(256).IsRequired();
        this.Property(m => m.PhysicalFileName).HasMaxLength(256).IsRequired();
        this.Property(m => m.Extension).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        this.Property(m => m.IsImage).IsRequired();
        this.Property(m => m.ThumbTiny).HasMaxLength(275).IsOptional();
        this.Property(m => m.ThumbSmall).HasMaxLength(275).IsOptional();
        this.Property(m => m.ThumbMid).HasMaxLength(275).IsOptional();
        this.Property(m => m.ByteSize).IsRequired();
        this.Property(m => m.StorageType).IsRequired();   

        this.Property(m => m.CreatedOn).IsRequired();
        this.Property(m => m.UpdatedOn).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

This mapping correctly generates an intermediate table named  NewsFileAttachment with two fields :

- NewsId
- AttachmentId

On News Entity when i call News.Attachments.Add(Attachment); it correctly adds records in both Attachment & NewsAttachment tables.

When i remove some list item from News.Attachments it correctly removes record from NewsAttachment table, but it doesn't delete record in FileAttachment table. I wanted to remove that too.

Can someone please suggest a better Fluent API configuration to achieve this?

Thanks,
Amit

**EDIT**
In my case FileAttachment stores files for various purpose. i've Blog entity that too have attachments. So, two intermediate tables BlogAttachments & FileAttachments. Now if i use WithOptional as (I can't use WithRequired as i need BlogId & NewsId both in FileAttachment table), i can get rid off intermediate table, but still delete doesn't delete record from FileAttachment table, it just make NewsId/BlogId NULL.

Any suggestion? Main thing is I do not wanted to create separate tables with all the fields i have in FileAttachment table.

Answer (score 0):

That's expected - as it creates many-to-many and extra table - the cascade only applies to that table.

> There is no direct 'FK' relationship in between your `News` and
>   `Attachment`, as it goes through a join table. And thus you cannot expect for e.g. attachment to be deleted, if the news does - as attachment could have other news relating to it.

See also this one - it's somewhat relevant.
[One to Many Relationship with Join Table using EF Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824135/one-to-many-relationship-with-join-table-using-ef-code-first)

i.e. if your structure permits don't explicitly create many-to-many (don't put collection on both sides, or similar in fluent config).

In your case **providing your 'attachments' are not reusable in between `News`** - then just put a collection navigation property in the `News` - and leave attachment w/o any - or make a 'FK', single instance navigation from Attachment (like a 'Parent') if you need it.

> On the other side, if an `attach...` could be parented by different
>   `news` records - then you shouldn't have cascade delete anyways.

**note:**  check your generated migration script - or SQL/Db - to see exactly what it creates - and make sure there is no intermediate table created - and only one 'FK' going from 'attachment' to 'news'.

**edit:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<News>()
    .HasMany(c => c.Attachments)
    .WithOptional() // or WithRequired (test to see which is better for you)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

...and make one `public ICollection<FileAttachment> Attachments {get;set;}` in the News.
(actually the collection property is all you need - but configuration is to be safe you get what you want)

That'd make you 1-to-many (or many-to-one), which is the nature of your data (as you said in comments) - and you can have cascade deletes.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response. My question is it still possible to keep intermediate table and still delete attachment when i remove relation with attachment from news? I know technically it may be incorrect, but as per my architecture i know that the single attachment record will be associated with one & only one other entity through intermediate table.

If that's not possible, can you suggest any other configuration without intermediate table which deletes the record from attachment table?

Comment: Hi Amit - **not possible** - for all I know and have seen. See my edit for what to do - that's the only way - and I think it 'fits' what you want.

Comment: Thanks @NSGaga, In my case FileAttachment stores files for various purpose. i've Blog entity that too have attachments. Two intermediate tables BlogAttachments & FileAttachments.  

Now if i use WithOptional as you suggested (I can't use WithRequired) as i need BlogId & NewsId both in FileAttachment table), i can get rid off intermediate table, but still delete doesn't delete record from FileAttachment table, it just make NewsId/BlogId NULL. Any suggestion? 

Main thing is I do not wanted to create seperate tables with all the fields i have in FileAttachment table.